# Static Template Member Crashes

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization, runtime

I've the following setup which crashes my dynamic library on loading.

```cpp
// in a.hpp

template <unsigned int Size>
class ATemplate : public A
{
public:
    ATemplate() : A(Size) 
    {
        init()
    };

    void init() 
    {
        // does stuff, it crashes here or "before" init() because "this" points to some random memory,...
    }
}

// in b.hpp

class B 
{
public:
    static const int Size = 128;
    static ATemplate<Size> Template;

}

// in b.cpp

ATemplate<B::Size> B::Template = ATemplate<B::Size>();
// also crashes like this:
ATemplate<B::Size> B::Template;
```

Afaik, the inheritance between A and B shouldn't be importent here, right? I have read stuff about the order of static objects initialization but since I don't really have multiple static objects, only really one, I don't think that this is important here.

Do you have an idea, what might be the issue here?

Comment: Any more info on crash?

Comment: Ehm, it is an access violation and what I can get out of the debugger is that the function init is called without an object. All variables are nonsense and "this" points to nothing.

Comment: I wonder if static initialization order fiasco is coming into play

Comment: I didn't really look into it because from what I've read it seems like the issue is that one static variable relies on another static variable. But in this case, I only have one static member, right?

Comment: did you try to initialize `B::size` in b.cpp just before initializing `B::template`?

Comment: I've added all of the `static const int` definitions to the .cpp, which now contains 
`const int B::Size`; 
just befor the init. Didn't help.

Comment: And I totally forgot to mention that this runs (without crashing) on OSX and  not on Windows. Compiled with VS13 and some older VS version. So it's not  a compiler issue.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It's a stack overflow. Now I have to find out why the compiler would decide to put a static member object on the stack,...